# Filter strings on word/phrase : Perl

Tags: regex, perl, filtering

I am new at perl and I am looking for some assistance on basically filtering a list of keywords. In short this is to a hash of strings against the same hash of words/phrases. This is to get the lowest common denominator and clean the list up.

For example say the list included the following:

```
bat
bat boy
bat-boy
bat&boy
bat:boy
bat's
bat-boy's
batman & bat boy
```

It should only match to the following:

```
bat boy            (because of bat)
batman & bat boy   (because of bat)
```

Regex is obviously the way to go, but I am stuck with the following as I can't use /b (word boundary match) as some of the words contain non word characters -,', &,:, etc.

What would be the best way to write the regex? I am checking $keyx against $keyz

Here is the regex:

```
if $keyx=~m/\Q$keyz\E/
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your requirement is unclear. You want to match `bat` to `bat boy` and `batman`, but not `bat-boy`, does that mean that you only want to match words where the key is surrounded by either letters or space?

Comment: Sorry, the second match for "batman & bat boy" should not match because bat is found in batman but rather after the & and in "**bat** boy"

Comment: So basically what you are saying is that you only want to match the whole word `bat` when it is followed by space (since you did not want the first `bat, ...` to match.)

Comment: The regex should be true for the phrase "batman & bat boy" if the token being searched off of is "bat", not because it finds "bat" in "batman" but rather because it finds the word "bat" in the second occurrence here: "& **bat** boy"

Comment: I'm with @TLP.  Are you looking for the whole stand-alone word "bat" with whitespace around it?  Why does "bat", the first word in your list, not match?  Maybe have a look at [grep](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to take care of the whole list at once

Comment: Mis-communication on my part. It should technically find the first plain "bat" as well. I am using this as a filter list, so I want to keep the first instance of the word as a filter. So yes, the regex should still find "bat" as well and I will do a boolean test so it doesn't delete itself.

Comment: I've reformatted your question to make the list of words a bit clearer. Maybe that'll help us understand and maybe help you understand how you can improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you're after, but I am guessing you want to match whole words only, no partials, and no words connected with non-letters. A way to accomplish this is to use negative look-around assertions:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

for (split /, */, <DATA>) {
    say if /(?<![^ ])bat(?![^ ])/;
}

__DATA__
bat, bat boy, bat-boy, bat&boy, bat:boy, bat's, bat-boy's, batman & bat boy
```

**Output:**

```
bat
bat boy
batman & bat boy
```

So we assert that the characters surrounding the key word is not not space.

Comment: OP stated that "bat" at the beginning of the list wouldn't match, not clear why...  Maybe it needs white space after it?